# Excel Services we ran into a problem

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, excel-web-access-webpart

I'm running into an issue with Excel Services Web Part. When i add a web part Excel Web Access and try to add a spreadsheet it errors out saying "We're sorry. We ran into a problem completing your request. Please try again in a few minutes.

Is there a way to troubleshoot this? can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Which SharePoint version (i.e. 2010, 2013, etc)?

Comment: In addition, please look at the server Application Event logs to determine what errors (if any) are being reported for "Excel Services Application".

Comment: This is what I'm getting in "Event 5239 (Excel Services Application) of severity 'Error' occurred 10 more time(s) and was suppressed in the event log"

Comment: SharePoint 2013 - sorry i just saw your first message.

Answer (score 0):

We have occasionally seen this in our environments - basically Excel Services may end up in a "non-valid" state (usually as a result of some server team doing a patch to the servers).  The usual solution is to simply restart the SharePoint server which is hosting the Excel Web Services application.

In my experience, it's usually enough run "IISRESET /noforce" on the command line for the server running Excel Web Services.

Further details here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee513104(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Tried those steps and still same issue. Any other ideas?